# VBA function works but causes Excel to crash

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing an excel sheet for a game to practice my coding because it has been two years since I last used VBA and my training was quite basic. If you don't mind looking at my code and giving me an idea of what might be going, I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry about the repetitiveness of the code. Below is a description of the code's function and the code itself.

Basically, I am having it read the contents of each talent on the video game character, which are in C9:G9. It reads each one to see if it matches the category selected by the user, and if it does, then it will acquire the rarity associated with the talent from C10:G10. After having that info, it uses the index function to read values from another sheet containing the percentages associated with the talent categories and rarity of the talent (say "Common Defense"). The row and column index values are decided by first searching through a list of talents sorted alphabetically (row value) and secondly assigning a column value by the rarity indicated from C10:G10.

The code seems to be executing the way I intended, but whenever I try to drag this function down a few rows of excel, it causes the program to freeze and crash.

```
Function TalentCalc(category As String) As Single

Application.Volatile

Dim Rarity As String
Dim TableVal As Single
Dim CategoryRow As Single
Dim RarityCol As Single

For i = 1 To 12 Step 1
    If category = Cells(3 + i, "M") Then
       CategoryRow = i
       i = 11
    End If
Next i


If Cells(9, "C") = category Then
    Rarity = Cells(10, "C")
    If Rarity = "Common" Then
        RarityCol = 1
    ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
        RarityCol = 2
    ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
        RarityCol = 3
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
    End If

    TableVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13"), CategoryRow, RarityCol)
    TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal
End If

If Cells(9, "D") = category Then
    Rarity = Cells(10, "D")
    If Rarity = "Common" Then
        RarityCol = 1
    ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
        RarityCol = 2
    ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
        RarityCol = 3
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
    End If

    TableVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13"), CategoryRow, RarityCol)
    TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal
End If

If Cells(9, "E") = category Then
    Rarity = Cells(10, "E")
    If Rarity = "Common" Then
        RarityCol = 1
    ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
        RarityCol = 2
    ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
        RarityCol = 3
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
    End If

    TableVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13"), CategoryRow, RarityCol)
    TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal
End If

If Cells(9, "F") = category Then
    Rarity = Cells(10, "F")
    If Rarity = "Common" Then
        RarityCol = 1
    ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
        RarityCol = 2
    ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
        RarityCol = 3
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
    End If

    TableVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13"), CategoryRow, RarityCol)
    TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal
End If

If Cells(9, "G") = category Then
    Rarity = Cells(10, "G")
    If Rarity = "Common" Then
        RarityCol = 1
    ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
        RarityCol = 2
    ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
        RarityCol = 3
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
    End If

    TableVal = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13"), CategoryRow, RarityCol)
    TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal
End If

End Function
```

Comment: *"crash"*: what specifically does this mean? Excel closes? You get a specific error message? It becomes unresponsive?

Comment: change the `i = 11` to `Exit For` in the for loop.

Comment: or simply remove `i=11` from the code.

Comment: Functions called form the grid should get ALL their needed input through the argument list, you should not be pointing to cells inside the function at all. Also, functions like these need proper error handling.

Comment: Application.Volatile wasn't causing the freezing followed by crash. (By crash I mean I get rainbow wheel - Mac - and then the program force quits itself).

Comment: @Vityata @Scott Craner Wow, the `Exit For` substitute for `i = 11` worked! Why was that causing issues? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

your code simplified:

```
Function TalentCalc(category As String) As Single
'should not need this, but uncomment if you really want it
'Application.Volatile

Dim Rarity As String
Dim TableVal As Single
Dim CategoryRow As Long
Dim RarityCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your worksheet

CategoryRow = 0: RarityCol = 0
On Error Resume Next
    CategoryRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(category, ws.Range("M:M"), 0)-3
    RarityCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(category, ws.Range("9:9"), 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If CategoryRow = 0 Or RarityCol = 0 Then Exit Function



Rarity = ws.Cells(10, RarityCol)
If Rarity = "Common" Then
    RarityCol = 1
ElseIf Rarity = "Rare" Then
    RarityCol = 2
ElseIf Rarity = "Epic" Then
    RarityCol = 3
Else
    MsgBox ("Pick a rarity.")
End If

TableVal = Worksheets("Talents").Range("B2:D13").Cells(CategoryRow, RarityCol)
TalentCalc = TalentCalc + TableVal



End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It did appear to work for the most part. The only problem is that it did not account for if the talent occurred in more than one location in the C9:G9 range (for instance, I can have a Common Defense and then a Rare Defense), but I blame that on my poor communication. Also, when I dragged the formula down to replicate the formula over all categories, it spit out the MsgBox saying "Pick a Rarity." Weird, cuz when I hit enter it just went away and did the calculation.